# Ranks composition of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have $a: A \to B$ and $b:B \to C$, where $a$ and $b$ are linear maps of vector spaces. Show that rank$(a) \geq $ rank $ (b \circ a)$ with equality if (not iff) $b$ is injective.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve this? I'm not exactly sure about the rank of a composition of two linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$\operatorname{rank}a=\dim(\operatorname{Im}a)$ and, if $E\subset E'$ are subspaces, $\;\dim E\le\dim E'$.